# How to add a value to an array inside a React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a `React Component` where I have a `Form` with multiple `Select`s.
The `options` of these `Select` components is passed to the `SearchComponent` as `props`.

I want to store the selected options in local `state`, and once the `Submit` of the form is pressed it is sent to the parent component that passes a function as a `prop` - `searchStatements`.

Since the select is multiple, I have an array of all the options that can be selected and stored in state.

```
class SearchComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        companies: [],
        years: [],
        currencies: []
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Form
              onSubmit={(e) => {
                  this.props.searchStatements(this.state.years, 
                          this.state.currencies,this.state.companies);
              }}
            >
                <Select
                  multiple=true
                  value={this.state.companies}
                  options={this.props.companies}
                  onChange={(e) => this.handleSelectChange('companies', e)}
                />
                <Select
                  multiple=true
                  value={this.state.years}
                  options={this.props.years}
                  onChange={(e) => this.handleSelectChange('years', e)}
                />
                <Select
                  multiple=true
                  value={this.state.currencies}
                  options={this.props.currencies}
                  onChange={(e) => this.handleSelectChange('currencies', e)}
                />
            </Form>
        );
    }

    handleSelectChange = (name, v) => {
        if (name === 'currencies') {
            const newArray = this.state.currencies;
            newArray.push(v);
            this.setState({'currencies': newArray});
        } else if (name === 'companies') {
            const newArray = this.state.companies;
            newArray.push(v);
            this.setState({'currencies': newArray});
        } else if (name === 'years') {
            const newArray = this.state.years;
            newArray.push(v);
            this.setState({'years': newArray});
        }
    };
}
```

---

The `initial state` is like this -

```
state = {
    companies: [],
    years: [],
    currencies: []
};
```

When a currency `USD` is added, it should become

```
state = {
    companies: [],
    years: [],
    currencies: ['USD']
};
```

Again, when a currency `GBP` is added, it should become

```
state = {
    companies: [],
    years: [],
    currencies: ['USD', 'GBP']
};
```

---

However, in the `handleSelectChange()`, after adding a couple of options, it becomes something like this -

```
state = {
    companies: [['GOOGLE'], ['GOOGLE', 'FACEBOOK']],
    years: [],
    currencies: [['USD'], ['USD', 'GBP']]
};
```

How do I change `handleSelectChange()` such that my final output looks something like this -

```
state = {
    companies: ['GOOGLE', 'FACEBOOK'],
    years: [],
    currencies: ['USD', 'GBP']
};
```

Comment: Did you debug to see what is the value of `v` in the `handleSelectChange` method?

Comment: It is giving an array - `["USD", "GBP"]`.

Comment: That means you are pushing an array into the existing array, see the problem(and perhaps the solution?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you use multiple values in the `Select` your e.g. `this.state.years` is an array of all years you selected. Hence you should assign the selected values (not push / append). So the `handleSelectChange` method should be

```
handleSelectChange = (name, v) => {
    this.setState({[name]: v});
};
```

Comment: Can you show that without ES6, I am fairly new to it and hence it is very difficult to understand.

Comment: I did this - `const some = {}; some[name] = v; this.setState(some);` and it seems to work. Could you tell me what the difference between the two is.

Comment: @yadav_vi Actually the direction I gave were correct bu there was a typo in the implementation of `handleSelectChange` that I provided. Your solution is correct but with ES6 you can use a shorter one: `this.setState({[name]: v})`